# Launch New Activity after correct login

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

On my last post I was told my structure was all messed up so I have changed it all around so I am not trying to do everything from one activity.

My loginactivity takes the login details then calls an asycn task to check if the user exists in my external database:

```
public class LogIn extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    }

    public void logIn(View view){
        EditText textU;
        EditText textP;

        //get userName and password from edit text
        textU   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Username);
        textP   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Password);

        String userName = textU.getText().toString();
        String passW = textP.getText().toString();

        Log.d("logIN", userName);
        Log.d("logIN", passW);


        //log in url
        String url = "myURL";
        String userURLComp = "u=" + userName;
        String pURLComp = "&p=" + passW;

        url = url + userURLComp + pURLComp;

        Log.d("URL", url);

        //async task for getting json
        new ReadLogInJSON(this).execute(url);





    }




}
```

My problem is that after the async task checks if a user is in the database I do not know how to initiate a new activity from the async task:

```
public class ReadLogInJSON extends AsyncTask
<String, Void, String> {

    Context c;

    public ReadLogInJSON(Context context)
    {
         c = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        //decode json here
        try{

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            String status = json.getString("status");

            if(status.equals("no")){
                //toast logIN failed

                String message = "Log In Failed";
                Toast.makeText(c,  message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            else{
                //get userName
                String userName = json.getString("userName");

                //get user ID
                String userID = json.getString("userID");


                //set preferences
                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("userName",userName);
                editor.putString("userID",userID);
                editor.commit();

                //launch new activity



            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }        
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

Update:

I tried launching it with this:

```
c.startActivity(new Intent(c, Search.class));
```

but nothing launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you really should suffix your class names logically, for instance "LoginAsyncTask" and "SearchActivity".
Secondly, yes, the proper (and only) way to start an activity is to call `startActivity(Intent)` :)
Try adding a log before and after `startActivity`, to verify if `onPostExecute` has really run.

Comment: did this, Log.d("logIN", "start new activity");
    c.startActivity(new Intent(c, Search.class)); and log is shown so it is getting there

Comment: What about a log after the start activity.  Also put a log inside the onCreate of Search.  Also, rename it to SearchActivity to make it clearer.

Comment: looks like its not executing the oncreate for some reason. Never ran the log in here:

http://pastebin.com/gAtJBvy0

Comment: that was it, usually it throws an error if I forget that though...Thanks!